# Make VS Code ignore files under /var/folders/

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

When I use the "Go to file..." function in VS Code (<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> on mac), VS Code lists files under the `/var/folders/...` path.

[image: Screenshot of the command palette]

Selecting one of the files under `/var/folders/` usually yields "The editor could not be opened because the file was not found.".

I'm pretty sure these are temporary files used by Git. The files under `var/folders/` appear as "recently opened" when I use git history features; comparing the file with previous versions of itself.

Is there a way to set VS Code so that only files in the current working directory show up?

Comment: Strange that using git features puts those temp-files in your recently opened list. I don't think that has happened for me before. What feature exactly are you referring to when you say "comparing the file with previous versions of itself"? How can that issue be reproduced?

Comment: Did you edit your workspace or user setting for `search.exclude` or `files.exclude`? The default `files.exclude` has `"**/.git": true,` by default, and `search.exclude` inherits from `files.exclude`.

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4088190?answerId=18852675022#18852675022

Comment: You are attempting to open a symlink hence the error.  Be sure to use `/private/var` on macOS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I added `**/var/folders/**` as a pattern in the `files.exclude` setting.

Does what I need.

Comment: Thanks, I was not adding ** at the end.

Comment: I had this same value in both `search.exclude` and `files.exclude` and it somehow prevented VS Code from hiding results from `/var/folders`. Keeping it only in `files.exclude` resolved the issue on my end. VS Code docs say that `search.exclude` _"Inherits all glob patterns from the #files.exclude# setting"_.

Comment: This setting does clear the cache from time to time, but files still show up after some time: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/203872.